# A small discrepency in the color tags at the bottom of the site

Tags: discussion

Just being picky here, but the "Photography" swatch of color is the same as the background of this site (not meta), perhaps it can be changed to maybe a shade lighter or darker, or get a black border. At first I thought it was just failing to load.

[image: the swatch]

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is a shade lighter. I know people have mentioned color issues before, especially with low contrast (or dynamic contrast) monitors.

Also, it's not an image, it's a colored `<span>` tag.

Comment: I see it now. Just very hard to notice on a CRT display. But it is indeed lighter.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere on meta.SO, there's a question and answer about this (I thought it was a question I asked or commented on, but I can't find it).  Basically, they started putting the little colour blocks on the list when it was just a few sites, but quickly ran into limitations - e.g. colours that look alike.  I'd imagine it's a low priority problem.

Oh, it was a question on meta.Cooking: https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/903/minor-problem-the-square-for-gaming-isnt-visible

Comment: Yes, it's not a big deal at all.